Find sum of maximum subarrays
This was asked in OA. Given an array of positive integers of size n.
For each item in array (indexes ranging from 0 to n - 1), find the size of the largest subarray containing the current item such that the current item is equal to the maximum element in that subarray, and add that size to the result (which starts at 0).
Example:
arr = [3,5,6]
Result = 6

Explanation:
i=0 => [3] = max subarray with 3 as maximum, size of sub-array is 1

i=1 => [3,5] = max subarray with 5 as maximum, size of sub-array is 2

i=2 => [3,5,6] = max subarray with 6 as maximum, size of sub-array is 3

Sum  = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6

Example:
arr = [ 1,2,1]
Result = 5

Explanation:
i = 0 => [1] max subarray, size = 1
i = 1 => [1, 2, 1] max subarray with 2 as maximum, size = 3
i = 2 => [1], max subarray with 1 as maximum, size = 1

Result = 1 + 3 + 1 = 5

Example:
arr = [1,1,1,1]
Result = 16

Explanation:
i = 0 => [1, 1, 1, 1] max subarray with 1 as maximum, size = 4
Same for i=1, 2, 3 => max subarray for each case is still [1,1,1,1] with size 4
Result = 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 16

Here is my code:
public class Main {

  public static int solve(int[] arr) {
    int n = arr.length;
    int result = 0;
    int currentMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      currentMax = Math.max(currentMax, arr[i]);
          
      if (arr[i] == currentMax) {
          size++;
          int backUp = size;
          for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
              if(arr[j] <= currentMax) {
                  size++;
              } else {
                  break;
              }
          }
        result += size;
        size = backUp;
      } else {
          size = 1;
          currentMax = arr[i];
          result++;
      }
    }

    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(solve(new int[]{3,5,6}));//6
    System.out.println(solve(new int[]{1,2,1}));//5
    System.out.println(solve(new int[]{1,1,1,1}));//16
  }
}

My code worked only for sample test cases and failed for remaining cases which are hidden, so I am not able to see them. What is the correct approach to solve this, the test cases failed saying wrong output, there are no time out errors.

what is the expected result for [6, 5, 3] ? (1st example reversed)

Largest sub arrays [6,5,3] ,  [5,3], [3] so result is 3+2+1=6

but is that the actual result? (the "correct approach" I would follow, is to find a case giving wrong results)

@user85421, yes that should be correct ourput, but i don't have running live site to verify it.

There you go: https://ideone.com/Nuulcw -- next step: debug (I guess the whole idea with currentMax is not working; but I really did not understand the algorithm)

@user85421, got it, to fix that i need to add another for loop inside else block also, but that will increase time complexity.

@SupportUkraine Yes, that appears to be a typo.

This problem just essentially requires finding the closest larger element on both sides for each element of the array. This can be done in O(n) with a monotonic stack.
public static long solve(int[] arr) {
    var dq = new ArrayDeque<Integer>(arr.length);
    int[] prevLarger = new int[arr.length], nextLarger = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        while (!dq.isEmpty() && arr[dq.peek()] <= arr[i]) dq.pop();
        prevLarger[i] = dq.isEmpty() ? -1 : dq.peek();
        dq.push(i);
    }
    dq.clear();
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        while (!dq.isEmpty() && arr[dq.peek()] <= arr[i]) dq.pop();
        nextLarger[i] = dq.isEmpty() ? arr.length : dq.peek();
        dq.push(i);
    }
    long ans = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) ans += nextLarger[i] - prevLarger[i] - 1;
    return ans;
}

